# Div alignment failed after adding content

Tags: html, css

I have a web page of the following layout.
The sidebar on the left is of the following css:

```
.sidebar { 
display: inline-block;  
top: 0;
width: 200px;
height: 1000px;
}
```

and the content on the right of css:

```
.content { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
```

But on adding any content inside the sidebar, the layout becomes:
[image]

[image]

The sidebar goes downwards and can't even make it go up by changing the 'top' value.

How can i Align a sidebar successfully in the left side of the content?

Comment: add vertical-align: top for .sidebar & content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `vertical-align: top;` declaration instead for both inline block columns to keep them at the top, as follows:

```
.sidebar, .content {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

> **['vertical-align'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)**
>
> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of
>   the boxes generated by an inline-level element.
>
> **top**
>   Align the top of the aligned subtree with the top of the line box.

CSS `top` property is only applicable to none-static positioned elements. It doesn't have any effect on `inline-block`s or any other inline level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Please explain why to make your answer worth:)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the fixed property:
    posistion: fixed

Try to check the width of oyu content, if it properly fits into this 200px width.

If you have firebug on your browser should give a good hand on debuging it.

Comment: can't use fixed if my sidebar has content longer than a single page

Comment: That's right. So try to put these 2 divs into another (called container for example) and set a vertical_align: top to it. It should keep both on top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of position rule or your top value has no effect. I would use `position: absolute;` . Using `fixed` is not ideal.

Comment: `top` is applicable to positioned elements other than `static` which of course is not the case here.

Comment: That element has no position set, so the default is static. As the questioner had already set `top: 0;` the best position option is absolute.

Comment: True but it's different from `You need to use position: absolute; or your top value has no effect` statement.